# In Excel, how do I copy a column when the column number is the result of a function and that result varies?

Tags: excel

I have some data where the column order is unknown, but the names of the columns are the same. For example:

```
Sale | Date     | User 
     |          |
 5  | 1/2/2020  | A
```

Or it could come as:

```
Date    |  User | Sale 
1/2/2020 | A    |  5
```

I am able to use the Match formula to get the column number.

Let's say that I use my formula and find that in this particular data set, Date is column A, User is column B, and Sale is Column C.

What formula would I use to copy and paste the column into a new sheet?

Comment: Why the "powerBI" tag?

Comment: Copy and then paste special values.

Comment: The formulas you seek are `MATCH` and `INDIRECT`.